# Question about a proof involving local rings: $R$ has exactly $3$ ideals, show that if $a,b\in I$ then $ab=0$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, maximal-and-prime-ideals, local-rings

I have a question regarding the following thread: [Commutative unitary ring with exactly three ideals.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2301407) I believe I've put the pieces together, but I am, for whatever reason, feeling uncomfortable.  So, combining the OP's initial attempt and MooS' second solution, we have:

First, let's prove that if $a\notin I$, then $a$ is a unit of $R$: suppose $a$ is not a unit of $R$.  Then, $I\subseteq I+(a)\subsetneq R$.  Since $1\notin I+(a)$ we have $I=I+(a)$, thus $a\in I$, a contradiction, so $a$ is a unit of $R$.

Now we want to show that if $a,b\in I$ then $ab=0$: By our first part, we conclude that any element not in $I$ must be a unit of $R$, thus any element in $I$ must be a non-unit of $R$.  So, $R$ is a local ring with maximal ideal $I$ (for the rest of this proof, even though MooS uses it, is it necessary that $I$ is finitely generated?  How do we know that?).

So, suppose $ab\neq 0$, then $I=(ab)=(a)(b)=(a)(a)$.  Let $a\in I$, from MooS, we consider the set $A:=\{x\in R:ax=0\}$, which he says is an ideal.  So, we will prove that this ideal is not $\{0\}$: If $a^2=0$, then done, so assume $a^2\neq 0$, then $(a)=(a^2)$ (I assume we can say this because $a^2=a\cdot a\implies a\in(a^2)\implies(a)\subseteq(a^2)$, and certainly $(a^2)\subseteq(a)$, so we get equality), thus $a=ba^2\implies a(ab-1)=0\implies ab-1\in A$.  Now, since $a\in I$, from part the first part of the problem, $a$ is a non-unit, thus $ab-1\neq 0$. (so, is this our contradiction, because $R$ has no zero divisors thus $a=0$?)

EDIT: From Severin's comment, I see why $I$ is finitely generated, and based on Mark's comment, I see why $(a)=I$, but I am still curious if my rationale behind why $a=0$ is valid.  Something still feels slightly off.

Comment: We know that $I$ is finitely generated as our ring has at most $3$ ideals. Pick $a\in I$, then $(a)\subseteq I$ is an ideal. If $(a)\neq I$, we can pick $b\in I \setminus (a)$, then $0\subsetneq (a)\subsetneq (a,b) \subseteq I \subsetneq R$. Thus, $(a,b)=I$, otherwise we would get a contradiction to the assumption that the ring in question has at most $3$ ideals.

Comment: We have $0 \subsetneq I \subsetneq 1$. Take some nonzero $a \in I$; then $0 \subsetneq A \subseteq I$, so $(a) = I$. So in fact, $R$ is a PID (not just Noetherian).

Comment: SeverinSchraven answered the first question - thank you!
@MarkSaving answered my second question - thank you!  
But, the last line, is my rationale correct?  

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can tell, the reasoning at the very end of your proof does not make any sense. Certainly, $R$ must have zero-divisors, since you are trying to prove that the product of any two elements of $I$ is zero!

In general, I think the structure of your proof is good, but you are over-complicating things. As Mark Saving notes in the comments, one may deduce that $I$ is principal, generated by some nonzero $x \in I$. Hence, it is enough to deduce that $x^{2} = 0$, as every element of $I$ is a multiple of $x$.

Indeed, suppose $x^{2} \neq 0$. Then the principal ideal generated by $x^{2}$ properly contains $\{0\}$ and is contained in $(x)$; by our hypothesis that $R$ contains three ideals, we must have $(x^{2}) = (x)$. In particular, there exists some $y \in R$ such that $x^{2}y = x$, whence rearranging and factoring gives $x(xy-1) = 0$. But as you noted in the first paragraph of your proof, $xy-1$ must be a unit, since if $xy-1 \in I$, then $1 \in I$, which contradicts $I \neq R$. Right multiplying both sides by $(xy-1)^{-1}$, we thus conclude that $x = 0$, the desired contradiction.

Comment: (On clicking the linked question, I see that MooS's proof is more or less the same as mine, up to minor differences in presentation which hopefully help. Oh well, let me know if you have questions!)

Comment: Thank you!  I see where my thinking was (way) off.  Thank you.  I will award the bounty this evening (MSE still says I can't award it for another 5 hours).  Thank you again!

Comment: @User7238 happy to help!